# Where i get the better idea to which type of application base should be in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop an application in which i doesn't any idea about how to create my app with which controller class i should i have gave?
My application first screen contain TabBarController and i have also inserting UINavigationController.
On above scenario i little bit confused which type of controller(confusion in TabBarController, NavigationBarController or simple ViewController ya windows based appliaction) should i take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a blank app from each template and inspect those projects closely to understand the differences between the different project templates. They are not very big. I think it is fundamental to understand how these templates work and how they create and initialize the root view controller and views. Once you got that understanding, you won't have a problem integrating multiple patterns (tab bar controller and navigation controller) into a single app.